# I added a few music tracks to my YouTube video with YouTube Studio. How can I automatically have them play sequentially instead of simultaneously?

Tags: youtube-studio

I have a 30-minute video YouTube. I use YouTube Studio to add some music from YouTube Audio Library. I've added 5 tracks from YouTube Audio Library. By default, these 5 tracks are stacked together at the beginning of the video, i.e. they will play at the same time at the beginning of the video.

How can I automatically have them play sequentially instead of simultaneously? I can drag and drop each track in the video timeline so that they are played subsequently, but it's rather tedious, especially since I will have to add music to more long videos in the future.

---

Screenshot from https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch002023.htm showing how to add music:

[image]

Screenshot showing the stacked tracks at the beginning of the video:

[image]

However, I want the tracks to be played sequentially, e.g.:

[image]